# Como pegar um elemento de uma lista pelo index em Elixir

Tags: elixir

Tentei pegar pelo modo tradicional: `[:a, :b, :c, :d][2]` porém eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
** (ArgumentError) the Access calls for keywords expect the key to be an atom, got: 2
(elixir) lib/access.ex:255: Access.fetch/2
(elixir) lib/access.ex:269: Access.get/3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir não é uma linguagem orientada a objeto, então o modulo `Enum` possui apenas três funções que permitem acessar um elemento de um array com base no seu index:

```
iex > Enum.at([:a, :b, :c, :d], 2)
:c
iex > Enum.fetch([:a, :b, :c, :d], 2)
{ :ok, :c }
iex > Enum.fetch!([:a, :b, :c, :d], 2)
{ :ok, :c }
```

Caso você tente acessar indices que não existem, você terá um resultado diferente para cada função:

```
iex > Enum.at([:a, :b, :c, :d], 9999)
nil
iex > Enum.fetch([:a, :b, :c, :d], 9999)
:error
iex > Enum.fetch!([:a, :b, :c, :d], 9999)
** (Enum.OutOfBoundsError) out of bounds error
   (elixir) lib/enum.ex:722: Enum.fetch!/2
```

> Fonte: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/633ba08446-accessing-a-single-element-of-a-list-by-index